# How to checki if project exist or not when programmtically create eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, rcp

by below code, I could create eclipse project programmatically, but I should check if project existing or not before creating it, if not existing, it should be created, otherwise, it should be refreshed, any hints will be more than welcome!

```
    IProjectDescription description = null;
    IProject project = null;
    description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(
            new Path(new File(projectfolder).getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/.project"));
    project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .getProject(description.getName());

    project.create(description, null);

    //project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new  org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor());

    project.open(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

`IProject` extends `IResource` which has the method [`exists()`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html&anchor=exists--):

```
if (!project.exists()) {
    project.create(description, null);
}
```

Comment: how should i refresh project
project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new  org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor());

or

 java.io.File file = iFile.getLocation().toFile();
      FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
      fOut.write("Written by FileOutputStream".getBytes());
      iFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);

my project is not copied to eclipse workspace by the way

Comment: @stewchicken `refreshLocal(...)` is only required when writing into a file not using the Eclipse API. Use `IFile.setContents(...)` instead.